# How to handle a file in ASP.net, that was uploaded from desktop application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I am using `WebClient.UploadFile` to upload a file to this kind of URL - http://example.com/file.aspx via HTTP POST method.

How can I get that file and save it to a sepecific location on the server? What code should I write inside file.aspx to do this?

When I search, all examples assume I use the file upload control. But how can I get and save a file sent via HTTP POST generally in ASP.Net?

I am using C#, so C# code example will be great. But I have no probs converting VB to C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the server-side page (which, BTW, ought to be an ASHX rather than an ASPX), use the `Request.Files` collection.

For example, you can write `Request.Files[0].SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Something"))`

Comment: Oh, thank you.. I will do more research on how to use that collection and get the files. Thanks for the sample code also.

Comment: You may want the `FileName` property as well.

Comment: You don't *have* to use ASHX over ASPX. ASPX pages are handlers too, and if there are no controls on the page (in other words, nothing in the ASPX file but the @Page directive) the performance penalty is going to be negligible.

Comment: @Kevin: So? ASHX is still simpler.

Comment: @Kevin, I didn't think of it to begin with because I have personally used .ashx so little. But on reflection I would agree that using a .ashx is a better option for the scenario presented. (update to my answer to come shortly)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should find this MSDN article suitable to your needs. [WebClient.UploadFile Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs.aspx)
You can see how the page_load is used to handle the file that is embedded in the http request from thew webclient

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    foreach(string f in Request.Files.AllKeys) {
        HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[f];
        file.SaveAs("c:\\inetpub\\test\\UploadedFiles\\" + file.FileName);

    }   
}
```

After reviewing comment from @SLaks I would agree that using a .ashx would be a 'better' result. The code should look something like:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Handler" %>

    using System;
    using System.Web;

    public class Handler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {

            foreach(string f in context.Request.Files.AllKeys) 
            {
               HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files[f];
               file.SaveAs("c:\\inetpub\\test\\UploadedFiles\\" + file.FileName);
             // alternatively:
             file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(@"\StorageFolder\",file.FileName);
             //thanks @SLaks.
            }
         }
     }
```

Comment: Use `Server.MapPath`, or a verbatim string literal and `Path.Combine`.

Comment: @Slaks that would be more fault tolerant, but not really on the topic of "getting the file from the client to the server" so I didn't concern myself with that...